# cannot retrieve large post data from $_POST

Tags: php, linux, apache, post, curl

I have a weird issue where I'm trying to post about 1GB of data, but when I receive the data the page/api gets executed without the post data. `$_POST` is empty, but `file_get_contents("php://input")` is not. I have set my php memory limit to -1 max post size to 1024M

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot this? here's my curl info:

```
Array
(
    url => https://myapi.dev/endpoint.json
    content_type => text/html
    http_code => 200
    header_size => 551
    request_size => 489
    filetime => -1
    ssl_verify_result => 0
    redirect_count => 1
    total_time => 30.591151
    namelookup_time => 0.000337
    connect_time => 0.002641
    pretransfer_time => 0.0056
    size_upload => 736249473
    size_download => 20
    speed_download => 0
    speed_upload => 24067400
    download_content_length => 20
    upload_content_length => 736249473
    starttransfer_time => 0.049208
    redirect_time => 15.965002
    certinfo => Array
        (
        )

    redirect_url => 
)
```

Comment: what web server are you using ?

Comment: @LuckyBurger I'm using apache

Comment: what version of php?

Comment: @LuckyBurger both sender and receiving servers use `PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15 with Suhosin-Patch`

Comment: hmmm well that doesnt make any sense... The only thing i can think of is the content_type is wrong

Comment: Suggests that it could be a php.ini problem. http://getluky.net/2009/02/24/php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available/

Comment: try application/x-www-form-urlencoded as content_type as well

Comment: @user962449 Apache has a limit as well make sure it's not set too low. Check `LimitRequestBody` parameter and set it higher than the 1GB. Also Increase max post size in PHP ini to a little large than 1024. I do that incase my data is slightly bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting php `memory limit` to `-1` and setting `max post size` to `1024M` may not be enough.

I also agree with @Panama Jack; apache could also be a factor if setting in php.ini all fails. You may have to take both into consideration. But in most cases like this its not an issue. It depends on your configuration.

`max_execution_time` might actually throw errors. I recommend changing your setting to `18000` (which is 5 hours) which is ok for `1GB`.

As far as the `php.ini` settings, I recommend setting them slightly higher than what you anticipate uploading. For example if you expect to upload 1G files then set the settings to `1536M (1.5G)`. This applies to `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size`, and `memory_limit`; its the combination of those 4 settings.

Answer (score 0):

check these in your `php.ini` and `php_info()`:

```
post_max_size - http://php.net/post_max_size
upload_max_filesize - http://php.net/upload_max_filesize
memory_limit - http://php.net/memory_limit
```

and

check these too:

```
max_execution_time  - http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time
set_time_limit - http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php
```

good luck! :-)